# How to ggplot two different objects that are within the same column?

Tags: r, ggplot2

#Data frame is Flower. Trying to scatter plot the growth (height, rate) of two different species of flowers (Rose, Daisy).

```
FlowerPlot <- ggplot(Flower, aes(Height, Rate))+
  geom_point(size=7, color = red)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(text = element_text(size=15)
```

#This gives me a scatterplot with all the species (Roses, Daisy) as one. How do I plot two species as two different colors on the same plot?

I tried `Factor` and it failed.

```
Flowerplot(flowers, aes(Height, Rate, color=factor(Flower$Species)))+
  geom_point(size=7, color = factor(Flower$Species)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(text = element_text(size=15))
```

#Is there a way to do something like `Flower$Species$Rose`? (I know I can't actually do this but something to this extent?
Note: I cannot post the entire data frame because it's massive.

Comment: Can you a subset of the data? Would be easy to give an answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `color` argument should probably be the `Species` column instead of `red`.

```
FlowerPlot <- ggplot(Flower, aes(Height, Rate))+
  geom_point(size=7, color = Species)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(text = element_text(size=15)
```

Don't think of the `color` argument as 'what color should I use to plot?'.  Instead, think of the argument as asking `what feature of the data should I use to group similar points together?'

By using the `Species` column, you are telling ggplot: "All points with the same `species` value should have the same color."

When you say that `factor(Flower$Species)` did not work, can you explain / show what it did and what you were expecting?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't have enough reputation to upvote you (feel free to upvote my question because it boosts my reputation). I receive the error "Error: Unknown colour name: daisy" when I tried just changing to ```Species``` as opposed to 'red'.

Comment: I was hoping ```Factor``` would separate them and assign different colors within the theme. My professor used an example using ```Factor``` for male and female and it worked without assigning colors.

Answer (score 0):

Ans: Need to remove everything from geom_point other than size and add one more `)` after Species

```
Flowerplot <- ggplot(Flower, aes(Height,
                                 Rate, color=factor(Species)))+
  geom_point(size=1)+
  theme_bw()
```